# React Redux -possible to have a call back in dispatch function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-reducers

Guys i am having some trouble or quite doubtful.

am having one component and one reducer.

### Reducer.js

```
import {
    ASSET_POPUP_GET_ENDPOINT,
} from 'apiCollection';
import { performGet } from 'services/rest-service/rest-service';

export const GET_ASSETS_LIST = 'stories/GET_ASSETS_LIST';


const initialState = {
    imgGroup: [],

    isLoading: false,

};

const modalUploadReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_ASSETS_LIST: {
            return {
                ...state,

                ImageJson:action.payload.imageGroup,

            };
        }
        case GET_ASSETS_LIST_ERROR: {
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading:false,
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const getModalClose = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: CLOSE_MODAL });
}

export const getListActionDispactcher = () => (dispatch) => {
    performGet(`${ASSET_POPUP_GET_ENDPOINT}`)
      .then((response) => {
        const payload = response.data;
        dispatch({ type: GET_ASSETS_LIST,
          payload: {
            ...payload,
            data: payload.results,
          } });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({ type: GET_ASSETS_LIST_ERROR, payload: err });
        throw err;
      });
  };



export default modalUploadReducer;
```

### and my component look like

it do have mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps 
and one of the function

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getCollection: () => dispatch(getListActionDispactcher()),
});

addDocumentClick = () =>{
    this.props.getAssetsCollection();
}
```

and is it possible to have some setState/manipulation of response after api response got from  reducer in the component

based on the response i need to do some changes in addDocumentClick.
Means something like this

```
addDocumentClick = () =>{
    this.props.getAssetsCollection().then(...based on response;
}
```

Comment: I'm not entire sure what you're asking, but if you're saying that `addDocumentClick` depends on data from the dispatched action's response, you should expose whatever is necessary for `addDocumentClick` to make its decisions as part of the props and/or state.

Comment: @DaveNewton my concern is i need to get the response back in addDocument function as like a call back function ans its response and do some magic based on the response

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question: what is the *nature* of the change you need to make based on the response? What *parts* of the response matter? My point is that if you need to make decisions based on response data then what you're asking for is not necessary.

Comment: @DaveNewton I can explain
I do have a dispatch function in reducer and i call the same from my component like this this.props.getAssetsCollection();

As soon as API get called and imageJson is the state which get enriched with data.

So the component do have its own state ,say assetLoaded need to be true ,which i need to make it true/false once i get the response back from reducer

now this.props.getAssetsCollection(); this wont allow me to check and change any other state or do magic in the component

Comment: This still doesn't make any sense to me. Put this logic in the reducer, or a different dispatch, or in `getDerivedStateFromProps`, or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way for solving this is setting a global `loading` flag and in your `componentDidUpdate()` method, checking for the value to determine that the action has just succeeded. You already seem to have the `isLoading` flag. Just set it when the action's dispatched, and unset it after it succeeds/fails. And in `componentDidUpdate()`:

```
function componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.isLoading && !this.props.isLoading) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Of course, you need to `connect()` your loading flag to your component to achieve this.

If all you care about is whether the assets list has changed, you can simply check for the change of that prop in `componentDidUpdate()`:

```
function componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.ImageJson !== this.props.ImageJson) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

---

Another solution is sending a callback to your action dispatcher, which makes your code more tightly coupled and I don't recommend, but it does work too. So, when you `connect()`, you can:

```
getCollection: (onSuccess) => dispatch(getListActionDispactcher(onSuccess)),
```

In your action dispatcher:

```
export const getListActionDispactcher = (onSuccess) => (dispatch) => {
  // ...once API finished/failed
  onSuccess(someData);
}
```

Finally, in your component:

```
this.props.getCollection((result) => {
  console.log('succeeded!', result);
  // hide modal, etc..
}
```

Comment: most recomment is ComponentDidMount?

If all you care about is whether the assets list has changed, you can simply check for the change of that prop in componentDidMount().->
Will it be like this

function componentDidMount(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.ImageJson && !this.props.ImageJson) {
    // do something
  }
}

Since ImageJson is the state which deals with assets. is this correct

@technophyle

Answer (score -1):

You are using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), and calling thunk will return a promise which will resolve in whatever you return in your thunk. Therefore, all you need to do is to add return value to `getListActionDispactcher`

```
export const getListActionDispactcher = () => (dispatch) => {
  // return this promise
  return performGet(`${ASSET_POPUP_GET_ENDPOINT}`)
    .then((response) => {
      const payload = response.data;
      dispatch({ type: GET_ASSETS_LIST,
        payload: {
          ...payload,
          data: payload.results,
        } });
      // return whatever you want from promise
      return payload
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: GET_ASSETS_LIST_ERROR, payload: err });
      throw err;
    });
};
```

.

```
addDocumentClick = () => {
  this.props.getAssetsCollection().then(payload => console.log(payload))
}
```

You should, however, look for ways to avoid this pattern to have your components decoupled from actions as much as possible for the sake of modularity

Comment: the only change is in getListActionDispactcher function we are returning return paylod, and it will be like this         case GET_ASSETS_LIST: {
            return {
                ...state,

                ImageJson:action.payload.imageGroup,

            };
        } any change to this ?

addDocumentClick = () => {
  this.props.getAssetsCollection().then(payload => console.log(payload))
} . will work accordingly ?

Comment: no, you don't need to change your reducer (given it worked properly before). Only changes I added (there are 2 of them in getListActionDispatcher) are needed  for what you are trying to achieve @midhunk

Comment: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined when i gave like that

Comment: then check for errors and make sure you copied both of my changes